# LNK1120 error with classes (Factory pattern). Not sure where it's coming from

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

Sorry if I posted too much code. I really don't know where the link error is coming from. It seems to be having a problem with this line:

```
dough = ingredientFactory->createDough();
```

in the CheesePizza class, but I don't know if the ingredientFactory reference or a problem in the Dough class. Can anyone please tell me why it won't link? ( I get a LNK1120 error ). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
class Dough  
{
    string m_dough; 
public:
    Dough() : m_dough( "Unknown dough" ) {}; 
    string setDough( string dough ) { m_dough = dough; }; 
    string getDough() { return m_dough; }; 

};



class ThinCrustDough : public Dough 
{
public:
    ThinCrustDough() { setDough( "Thin crust dough" ); }; 
}; 


class PizzaIngredientFactory
{
 public:
    PizzaIngredientFactory() {}; 
    Dough *createDough();
    Sauce createSauce();
    Cheese *createCheese();
};



class NYPizzaIngredientFactory : public PizzaIngredientFactory
{
    Cheese *cheese; 
public: 
    NYPizzaIngredientFactory(){}; 
    Dough *createDough() { return new ThinCrustDough; };
    Sauce *createSauce() { return new MarinaraSauce; };
    Cheese *createCheese() { return new ReggianoCheese; };
}; 


 class Pizza
 {
    string m_size; 
    string m_description;
    string m_type; 

    PizzaIngredientFactory *ingredientFactory; 
    string m_name;
    string m_dough;
    string m_sauce;
    string m_cheese; 
    Dough dough; 
    Sauce sauce;
    Cheese cheese;

public:

    Pizza() : m_description("Unknown Pizza"), m_size(" ,Unknown Size ") {}; 
    Pizza( PizzaIngredientFactory *ingredientFactory ){ this->ingredientFactory = ingredientFactory; }; 

    string name() { return m_name; };
    string getName() { return m_name; }; 
    void setName( string name ) { m_name = name; };

    string getDescription() { return m_description; };
    string setDescription( string setdescription ) { return m_description = setdescription; }; 
    string getSize() { return m_size; };
    string setSize( string setsize ) { return m_size = setsize; };
    string getType() { return m_type; }; 
    string setType( string settype ) { return m_type = settype; };  
    virtual void prepare() = 0;
    void bake();
    void cut(); 
    void box(); 
    void orderPizza(); 

};


void Pizza::prepare()
{
    Pizza *pizza; 
    cout << "Preparing " << pizza->getName() << endl;
    cout << "Adding toppings : " << endl; 

    for ( vector<string>::iterator itr = toppings.begin();
           itr != toppings.end();
           ++itr )
    {
        cout << "    " <<  *itr;
    }

}; 



void Pizza::bake()
{
    cout << "Bake for 25 minutes at 350 degrees" << endl;
}; 



void Pizza::cut()
{
    cout << "Cutting the pizza into diagonal slices" << endl;
};



void Pizza::box()
{
    cout << "Place pizza in official PizzaStore box" << endl; 
};



class CheesePizza : public Pizza
{
    PizzaIngredientFactory *ingredientFactory;
    Pizza *pizza;
    Dough dough;
    Sauce *sauce; 
    Cheese *cheese; 

public:
    CheesePizza() { }; 
    CheesePizza( PizzaIngredientFactory *ingredientFactory ){ this->ingredientFactory = ingredientFactory; }; 
    void prepare(){

        cout << "Preparing " << getName() << endl; 

        dough = ingredientFactory->createDough();

    }; ; 

}; 




class PizzaStore 
{
    PizzaIngredientFactory *factory; 

public:
    PizzaStore() {}; 
    PizzaStore( PizzaIngredientFactory *factory ) { this->factory = factory; }; 
    Pizza *orderPizza( string type )
    {
        Pizza *pizza; 

        pizza = createPizza( type );  
        pizza->prepare(); 
        pizza->bake();
        pizza->cut();
        pizza->box();

        return pizza;
    }

protected:
    virtual Pizza *createPizza( string type ) = 0; 
}; 


class NYPizzaStore : public PizzaStore
{
    Pizza *pizza; 

public:
    NYPizzaStore() {}; 
    NYPizzaStore( Pizza *pizza ){ this->pizza = pizza; }; 

protected:
    Pizza *createPizza( string item )   
    {
        Pizza *pizza = NULL; 
        PizzaIngredientFactory *ingredientFactory = new NYPizzaIngredientFactory;

        string type = "New York Style"; 

        string cheese = "cheese"; 
        if ( strcmp( cheese.c_str(), item.c_str() ) == 0 ) 
        {
            pizza = new CheesePizza( ingredientFactory );
            pizza->setType( type + " Cheese Pizza" );
        }

        return pizza;
    }
 };
```

Comment: It must have been preceded by an LNK2001. have you defined all methods for the classes? The `PizzaIngredientFactory` functions should be declared as virtuals.

Comment: Two things: The member functions in `PizzaIngredientFactory` should be virtual, maybe even pure virtual. The second thing is that the declaration of `createSauce` differs in `PizzaIngredientFactory` and `NYPizzaIngredientFactory`.

Comment: For consistency, I'd put `this->` in front of `dough`.

Comment: @Zenexer I wouldn't. For consistency, I'd remove all `this->`

Comment: @VJovic That's just a matter of style.  From what I saw, he uses `this->` everywhere else, so he might as well add it there.  (Personally, I never use `this` unless I'm passing it as a parameter in a method call.)

Comment: @Zenexer Yes, I saw. `this->` is just a noise. The best code is the one that is not there, because there is less to read and it's less error prone :)

Comment: The defining the methods as virtual fixed it. Thank you all of you.

Comment: @david Would you consider posting your original comment as an answer, since it seems to have solved the problem?  It might be useful to the next unlucky soul who gets this homework assignment, hehe.

Comment: @Zenexer: Did it, though Joachim's answer was better, I think.

Comment: @david Eh, doesn't really matter; as long as the answer gets up there.  I just saw yours first.

Answer (score 1):

(If I recall correctly this comes from Head First:Design patterns, c++-ized)
Your problem is that you have declared some  functions in `PizzaIngredientFactory`
 but you haven't defined them, causing the linker to raise an error message. You can determine the cause by looking at the errors. The visual studio linker will list them in an [LNK2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) message. 
You can solve this problem by declaring those functions as virtuals in `PizzaIngredientFactory`. As Joachim Pileborg suggested, pure virtual is favorable over 'plain' virual, since the pattern this is abstract factory.
Another thing nice to keep in mind is that classes designed for inheritance should have a virtual destructor (but it has to be defined in the base class also, otherwise another linker error will occur).